# Why does jersey jackson/json processing fail on polymorphic types?

Tags: jackson, entity, filtering, jersey-2.0

I have a simple example program that duplicates what I believe is a bug, but in case there are real experts out there who know better than I do what's going on, I'll post my issue here.

Here is my Main class:

```
public class Main {
    public static final String BASE_URI = "http://0.0.0.0:8080/myapp/";

    public static HttpServer startServer() {
        final ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig()
                .packages("com.example")
                .register(EntityFilteringFeature.class)
                .register(JacksonFeature.class)
        ;

        return GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(URI.create(BASE_URI), rc);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final HttpServer server = startServer();
        System.out.println(String.format("Jersey app started with WADL available at "
                + "%sapplication.wadl\nHit enter to stop it...", BASE_URI));
        System.in.read();
        server.shutdown();
    }
}
```

And here's my Jersey resource:

```
@Path("myresource")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class MyResource {

    public static class InnerDataBase {
    }

    public static class InnerData extends InnerDataBase {
        public String item1 = "item1";
        public String item2 = "item2";
    }

    public static class Data {
        public String name = "Got it!";
        public InnerDataBase innerData = new InnerData();
    }

    @GET
    public Data getIt() {
        return new Data();
    }
}
```

The item of note here is that I'm marshalling a class that contains a field whose concrete instance is a derived class with two fields ("item1" and item2") but whose type is actually that of the base class which has no fields. When I run this server and hit the endpoint, I get this:

```
{"name":"Got it!","innerData":{}}
```

If I comment out registration of EITHER the EntityFilteringFeature OR the JacksonFeature, the output becomes (as it should):

```
{"name":"Got it!","innerData":{"item1":"item1","item2":"item2"}}
```

**Conclusion:** It appears that the the Jackson media feature is not quite ready for prime time yet in Jersey 2.26-b09.

**Additional Thoughts:** When I comment out the JacksonFeature, I presume entity filtering is then done with the default Moxy provider. When I comment out EntityFilteringFeature, I presume then that jackson just takes over and handles marshalling for Jersey automatically.

Here's the dependencies section of my pom:

```
<properties>
    <jersey.version>2.26-b09</jersey.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-grizzly2-http</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-binding</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-entity-filtering</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- both json modules may be included as they're enabled in the ResourceConfig -->
    <dependency>    <!-- use this one when using moxy json processing -->
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>    <!-- use this one when using jackson json processing -->
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.9</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Your thoughts? Am I missing something important here?